# Dose aws spot market still refund when the spot instance is revoked in its first hour?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As described in the title, I remember before in AWS spot market that if a spot instance is revoked in its first hour, all the charges would be refunded fully. Does this policy still work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the EC2 service terminates or stops the spot instance in the first hour, then you are not charged.

To quote the [Spot Instances FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#spot-instances):

> If your Spot instance is terminated or stopped by Amazon EC2 in the
>   first instance hour, you will not be charged for that usage. However,
>   if you terminate the instance yourself, you will be charged to the
>   nearest second. If the Spot instance is terminated or stopped by
>   Amazon EC2 in any subsequent hour, you will be charged for your usage
>   to the nearest second. If you are running on Windows and you terminate
>   the instance yourself, you will be charged for an entire hour.

Comment: You’re welcome. I had to search a little to find it too.